# Error when running Express server using nodemon alongside react dev server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have both the server and client side code in one folder, the react app is in a `/client` folder in the root of my project, I am not able to run the two servers concurrently.

I used `npx create-react-app` to set up my react application,     NOTE: using `npx`, React files are installed using **yarn** when in my server Express app I used **npm**.   I also installed `concurrent` in my server app to have the two servers running together, but I am getting an unclear error when I try so.

```
// here is how I put together my scripts in the package.json
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "yarn start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently  \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
}

// this is my folder structure

├── node_modules
├── client // the client folder is my react app
├── config
├── models
├── routes
├── validation
├─package.json
├─server.js
```

here is a screenshot to the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmnZL.jpg) I am getting.
please ask for more info about the code if needed, thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you already have something listening on port 5000. That's what the error means.

Comment: I did kill any process running on the port 5000 following these [steps](http://www.codeman.in/blog/windows-kill-process-by-port-number-157), now I am getting this error `'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, any Idea why ?!. PS. react dev server runs separately with no issues.

Comment: Is this new error with or without the changes suggested in the answer? After killing anything on port 5000 I would go back to your original dev command and try again if you haven't already. Also, does your server run okay on its own (npm run server)?

Comment: this error occurred with the changes in the link, I made sure nothing is running on port 5000, then I tried to run my dev command, then I got this error, and the two servers are working perfectly fine when I run them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "( cd ./client && yarn start)",
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"", // (if you're using yarn for server as well...)
  },
```

Comment: I did, but I got this error now `'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Comment: @MoSwilam Sometimes it helps to delete the node modules folders (and the yarn.lock but NOT package.json) on both server and client and reinstall everything...

Comment: tried it also, got the same eror :\, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you post your package.json here...? @MoSwilam

Comment: here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/O6DcxMF) to the package.json